# (In VB.net 2012) Obtain "xlApp" from each running Excel instances?

Tags: excel, vb.net

[based on this code](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1080611/Get-a-Collection-of-All-Running-Excel-Instances)

I am trying to enumerated each excel instances and then obtain the "xlApp" object for each of these instances

NOTE : You can create multiple Excel instances by clicking the Excel link in your startmenu but keep the left-alt button press while it starts and it will ask you if you want to create a new instance

My code so far (compiles and runs without error, but does not return xlApp objects in a list)

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Text
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Module Module1

    Private Const EXCEL7 As String = "EXCEL7"
    Private Const GW_CHILD As Integer = 5
    Private Const GW_HWNDNEXT As Integer = 2

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
    Private Function FindWindowEx(ByVal parentHandle As IntPtr, _
                                  ByVal childAfter As IntPtr, _
                                  ByVal className As String, _
                                  ByVal windowTitle As String) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("Oleacc.dll")> _
    Private Function AccessibleObjectFromWindow(ByVal hwnd As Integer, _
                                                ByVal dwObjectID As UInteger, _
                                                ByVal riid As Byte(), _
                                                ByRef ptr As Excel.Window) As Integer
    End Function

    Private Function EnumerateExcelInstances() As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Excel.Application)
        Dim excelInstances As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Excel.Application)()

        Try
            Dim hwnd = FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, "XLMAIN", Nothing)

            While hwnd <> IntPtr.Zero
                Dim hwndChild = FindWindowEx(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, EXCEL7, Nothing)

                If hwndChild <> IntPtr.Zero Then
                    Dim ptr As Excel.Window = Nothing
                    Dim guid As New Guid("{00020400-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}")
                    AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hwndChild.ToInt32(), &HFFFFFFF0UI, guid.ToByteArray(), ptr)

                    If ptr IsNot Nothing Then
                        excelInstances.Add(ptr.Application)
                    End If
                End If

                hwnd = FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, hwnd, "XLMAIN", Nothing)
            End While
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " & ex.Message)
        End Try

        Return excelInstances
    End Function

    Sub Main()
        Dim excelInstances = EnumerateExcelInstances()

        For Each xlApp In excelInstances
            Console.WriteLine("Excel Process ID: " & xlApp.Hwnd)

            If xlApp.Workbooks.Count > 0 Then
                Console.WriteLine("Opened Workbooks:")

                For Each wb As Excel.Workbook In xlApp.Workbooks
                    Console.WriteLine(wb.Name)
                Next
            Else
                Console.WriteLine("No workbooks are open.")
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

Which you can compile by saving it to listexcel.vb using the following vbc command (you might have to adjust your path to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll and you must have vbc in your path)

```
vbc /r:C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll /r:System.dll listexcel.vb
```

You can list each window handle of each Excel process with the following code.  (tested working)

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Text

Module Module1

    ' Define the class name of the Excel application main window
    Private Const xlMainWindowClass As String = "XLMAIN"

    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("Running Excel instances:")

        ' Enumerate all windows
        EnumWindows(Function(hWnd, lParam) As Boolean
                        ' Get the window's class name
                        Dim className As New StringBuilder(256)
                        GetClassName(hWnd, className, className.Capacity)

                        ' If the window is an Excel main window, print its handle
                        If className.ToString() = xlMainWindowClass Then
                            Console.WriteLine(hWnd.ToString())
                        End If

                        ' Continue enumeration
                        Return True
                    End Function, IntPtr.Zero)
    End Sub

    ' Delegate and methods for EnumWindows
    Private Delegate Function EnumWindowsProc(hWnd As IntPtr, lParam As IntPtr) As Boolean

    <DllImport("user32.dll")>
    Private Function EnumWindows(callback As EnumWindowsProc, lParam As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll")>
    Private Function GetClassName(hWnd As IntPtr, lpClassName As StringBuilder, nMaxCount As Integer) As Integer
    End Function

End Module
```

which you can compile and test with

```
    vbc /r:C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll /r:System.dll listexcelpidhwnd.vb
```

And for now my goal is to print all workbook names for each running excel instance, test code for that is below (tested working)

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = Nothing
        Dim xlWorkbooks As Excel.Workbooks = Nothing

        Try
            ' Get a reference to Excel
            xlApp = DirectCast(System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application"), Excel.Application)
        Catch
            ' If Excel is not running, exit
            Console.WriteLine("Excel is not running.")
            Return
        End Try

        ' Get a reference to the Workbooks collection
        xlWorkbooks = xlApp.Workbooks

        ' Enumerate the workbooks
        If xlWorkbooks.Count > 0 Then
            Console.WriteLine("Opened workbooks:")
            For i As Integer = 1 To xlWorkbooks.Count
                Console.WriteLine(xlWorkbooks.Item(i).Name)
            Next
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("No workbooks are open.")
        End If

        ' Clean up
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlWorkbooks)
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlApp)
    End Sub
End Module
```

which you can compile and test with

```
    vbc /r:C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll /r:System.dll listworkbooks.vb
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/office-suite-issues/getobject-createobject-behavior

Comment: This method only returns the first excel instance's xlApp object. The solution is to use AccessibleObjectFromWindow however something's wrong with my code and I'm not sure what